# Python Enter variable to assign to text box before code runs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, split

Is it possible in python to have it prompt the user for numerous integers (separated by white space, which I'm guessing would be the default anyway) and then having python split these integers up and assigning them to different variables? I'd like to have my code after this cycle through these integers, but I'll work that bit out later!

I'm guessing the syntax would be something like:

```
x = raw_input("Enter list of integers separated by a space:")
x.split()
```

But then how would you assign a new variable to each? Would it even be necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're partway there.

Split the input on space, convert each part to an integer, and store back into a new list:

```
x = raw_input("Enter list of integers separated by a space:")
integers = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
```

Comment: Clean and precise

Answer (score 1):

Well you solution already works, but why should you assign a new variable to each value?

```
x = raw_input("Enter list of integers separated by a space:")
a = x.split()
for val in a:
  print(int(val))
```

or

```
for val in x.split():
  print(int(val))
```

Comment: hey @jobias, would I not have to assign them each to a variable to then have selenium input them into a text box, loop back and input the next one, loop back etc...?